# Removing a part from a device configuration file using RegEx In Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace, config

I am working on a perl project. In which I need to remove some configurations from a device's running config.

In my backend code i am getting the device config in the form of a scalar given below:

```
my $node_config = $self->get_node_config($node);
```

Now, when I dump the content of `$node_config` on the console, I get the device running config which contains some configurations that I want to remove. 
I want to remove all the `'aaa'` related configurations and `'enable passwords'` configuration full lines.

For Example, I have the configurations in the following way:

```
enable secret 3 *******

enable passwords something

aaa authentication login

aaa authentication login

aaa authentication enable

aaa authorization console

aaa authorization config
```

I want to remove all the similar lines in the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to replace the lines with an empty string.

```
s/(?:^|\n)(?:enable passwords|aaa) .*//g
```

- `(?:^|\n)` Matches the start of string or a newline (match start of line).
- `(?:enable passwords|aaa)` both options as literals.
- `.*` the rest of the line.

**Code**

```
my $node_config = "
enable secret 3 *******
enable passwords something
aaa authentication login
aaa authentication login
aaa authentication enable
aaa authorization console
aaa authorization config";

$node_config =~ s/(?:^|\n)(?:enable passwords|aaa) .*//g;

print $node_config;
```

**Output**

```
enable secret 3 *******
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/E5atgJ)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot..!! It worked like a charm..!! :) Although I was thinking If i want to replace the following line : 

username ******* secret 5 *******

with

username default default

Then what should I do..!! :)

Comment: Perhaps something like **[this](http://ideone.com/8tcLe9)**, but it's not clear what you're trying to do. If you can't manage to solve it with this info, ask a new question.

Comment: Hey Mariano I solved it...!! :) Used the Following RegEx :-

$node_config =~ s/(?:^|\n)(?:username).*/\nusername default password default/g;

Answer (score 1):

This filters out the matching lines

`perl -ne 'if (!/^aaa|enable passwords/) { print $_}'` *config_file_name*

The same can be done by a grep command line

`grep -v -E '^aaa|enable passwords'` *config_file_name*